# MySQL syntactical error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute the following code on my hosts mysqladmin page.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `follow`(IN in_follower INT(11), IN in_followee VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO follower (follower_id, followee_id) VALUES (in_follower, (SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = in_followee));
END
```

The error I get is :

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Why is this error happening here? When I used that code in MySQL Workbench it ran fine.

Comment: You probably need to set an alternate `DELIMITER` in the mysqladmin console.  Is it phpmyadmin or something else? How that is done depends on the client. The MySQL command line client has a command `DELIMITER`, phpmyadmin has an input field to set, your web console may have a different method.

Comment: Actually, in this case you could just remove `BEGIN` and `END` and not worry about statement delimiters...

Comment: I tried this code CREATE PROCEDURE `follow` ( IN in_follower INT( 11 ) , IN in_followee VARCHAR( 45 ) ) INSERT INTO follower( follower_id, followee_id ) VALUES ( in_follower, ( SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = in_followee ) ); and got this error #1547 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted

Comment: Could it be that my host has stored procedures disabled ?

Answer (score 2):

Try thisone,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `follow` 
(
    IN in_follower INT (11) ,
    IN in_followee VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO follower ( follower_id , followee_id )
        SELECT in_follower AS follower_id, user_id
        FROM user
        WHERE username = in_followee;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I tried that and got the following error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `follow` 
(
    IN in_follower INT (11) ,
    ' at line 1

Comment: This won't work in PHPMyAdmin. It has its own input field for the delimiter, as `DELIMITER` as a command is specific to the MySQL command line client.

Comment: try removing delimiter and see if it works, @MichaelBerkowski let me download wamp so i can test it :)